# How to access stored values of other Chrome or Firefox extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need a clarification regarding the Chrome local storage access. Say, I have designed two Chrome extensions - **Extension1** and **Extension2**. I set a value **val_ext1** in Extension1 and **val_ext2** in Extension2 by calling "chrome.storage.sync.set".

I need to know whether I can access val_ext2 from Extension1 and val_ext1 from Extension2. If yes, then it will be helpful if someone can share some pointers on how to do the same. Additionally, I would also like to know whether is it the same for Mozilla extensions as well.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the solution. I have another doubt as well. What if one extension is mine and the other one isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Chrome

No, this is not possible.  `chrome.storage.*` is only accessible to the extension which stored the data.  There is no API which would allow you to access data stored in a [StorageArea](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea).

If you want to gain access to that data, you will need to use [Cross-extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external). However, this requires both extensions to be written to facilitate doing so. This is unlikely to be the case for an extension which you do not control.

### Firefox

In this regard (and in most other ways), Firefox WebExtensions have the same restrictions as Chrome extensions.

[Other types of Firefox extensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910014948/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/13574/introduction#t=201709100149489262324) are *significantly* more capable than WebExtensions/Chrome extensions. Using any of the other types of Firefox extensions, you should be able to write code which will grant you access to data stored in a different WebExtensions' StorageArea data. The WebExtensions APIs are primarily written as JavaScript. Other types of Firefox extensions have the ability, if they choose, to modify the JavaScript that is shipped with Firefox. Thus, while there is not a specific API available that would allow you to do so, you could write an extension to do it, even if that requires that extension to modify the JavaScript code which ships with Firefox.<sup>1</sup> Obviously, modifying the stock Firefox code should not be your first choice of how to accomplish something, but it may be what is needed to accomplish what you desire.

---

1. [One of my extensions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/change-bookmark-recent-folder-) modifies the stock Firefox code in order to change a value in one file from being defined as a `const` to being configurable via an options page. In that particular extension, the code is completely replaced. However, it is also possible to programmatically change portions of the Firefox code.